# Network stream read when socket is closed

Tags: c#, networkstream

This question is very simple. Read the [documentation about NetworkStream Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream.read?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_Sockets_NetworkStream_Read_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_) and I quote:

> Returns
>   Int32 
>   The number of bytes read from the NetworkStream, or 0 if the socket is closed.

And later

> IOException 
>   The underlying Socket is closed.

Which is true? Clearly both can not be true at the same time, there must be a difference. (It seems that the former is true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both

If the **client socket** (which binded with the `NetworkStream`) is closed before you call `Read`, it throws an IO exeption.

If the **server socket** is closed during (or before) `Read`, it may return 0, that means the server sent nothing.

Some examples:

```
var server = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
var client = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

/* Init the server socket */
server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 19998));
server.Listen(50);
server.BeginAccept(ar =>
{
    var server2 = server.EndAccept(ar);
    //server2.Close(); // Read will return 0
},
null);

/* Init the client socket */
client.Connect(IPAddress.Loopback, 19998);
NetworkStream stream = new NetworkStream(client);
//client.Close(); // Read will throw IOException
var buf = new byte[128];
int read = stream.Read(buf, 0, 128);
```

Comment: How exactly a socket can be closed *during* Read? I am trying to understand why the server I am using is sending me "0 bytes"